# My iPhone 4S says no storage available even though there should be space available

Tags: iphone, storage, space

The first time I got the message, I was willing to believe I just needed to free up some space, so I uploaded all my photos and cleared them off of my phone and deleted a few apps I no longer use, which should have opened 2-3GB in storage space. But the phone still shows 13.5GB used, 0 bytes available. When I add up the usage - 6.6GB for facebook, 1.1GB for music, and 1.45GB by other apps and games for a total of 9.15GB - it does not total the 13.5GB the phone shows in use. I don't suppose there is an easy way of fixing this?

Comment: try a hard reset, hold the top and home buttons until the phone restarts.

Comment: Do you use iTunes Match?  I just learned in another question this could be you issue.

Comment: Nope. Phone's jailbroken, and I use an older version of iTunes.

Comment: I suggest letting us know what version of iTunes you're using, what OS is on the phone, and what software you're using to Jailbreak.